# JSON.parse not working in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, json, cordova

I'm working on a program that needs to save user data in a file as a JSON format. It is doing fine saving my data as JSON but when I try to use `JSON.parse` to parse my stored JSON it doesn't work.
Here is my code for storing the data:

```
function writeUser(data) {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs){
        fs.root.getFile('user.data', {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fe){
            fe.createWriter(function(writer){
                //Its converts my data to JSON here
                writer.write(JSON.stringify(data));
                //It displays this so I knows its been written!
                console.log('File written');
            }, failwrite);
        }, failwrite);
    }, failwrite);
}
function failwrite(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

And here is the code that read my data:

```
function readUser(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs){
        fs.root.getFile('user.data', null, function(fe){
            fe.file(function(file){
                return readAsText(file);
            }, failread);
        }, failread);
    }, failread);
}
function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    return reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Its returns my data fine as a string, Here is what I get as a string `{"status":"true","id":"1","password":"xx"}`, But when I use JSON.parse with my data it returns unidentified object. Here is the part where it uses `JSON.parse`:

```
readUser();
var user = JSON.parse(readUser());
console.log(user);
```

It won't even run my console.log command with the parsed JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the readUser does not return anything. the content of the file is available in the readAsText callback. you have to json parse the evt.target.result and continue from there.

Comment: So I would use change my evt.target.result to `JSON.parse(evt.target.result)` and then return `reader.readAsText(file);`?

Answer (score 2):

For reading use:

```
jsonVariable = jQuery.parseJSON(evt.target.result);
```

For writing use:

```
writer.write(JSON.stringify(propFileJson));
```