# How to read json file located in project folder in iPhone PhoneGap using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, json, cordova

I have to read a JSON file from folder that is located in a project.

I am using the following code:

```
var obj = "www/places.json";
```

How can I read a JSON file located in project folder `www` in iPhone PhoneGap using Javascript?

Comment: Have look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908717/json-parse-not-working-in-phonegap it has an example how to read a file and parse it as JSON.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would read it just like it is on your server.

## Solution 1 - jQuery

If jQuery usage is not a problem then use it like this:

```
//Load categories object JSON
jQuery.getJSON("categories.json", function(data){         
    // data is yours parsed object
});
```

### Example :

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <script src="http://www.fajrunt.org/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>       
    <title>Read JSON Demo</title>

    <script>    
        jQuery.getJSON("categories.json", function(data){         
            alert(data.balance);
        });         
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Read JSON Demo
</body>
</html>
```

JSON file :

```
{"balance":1000.21,"num":100,"nickname":null,"is_vip":true,"name":"foo"}
```

## Solution 2 - Pure javascript

If you want to use only vanilla javascript then this is a solution for you

```
var xmlhttp;
var jsonObject;

// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
// code for IE6, IE5
else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        jsonObject = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        alert(jsonObject.balance);                       
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","categories.json",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

### Example :

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Read JSON Demo</title>

    <script>
        var xmlhttp;
        var jsonObject;

        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        // code for IE6, IE5
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                jsonObject = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                alert(jsonObject.balance);                       
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","categories.json",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Read JSON Demo
</body>
</html>
```

JSON file :

```
{"balance":1000.21,"num":100,"nickname":null,"is_vip":true,"name":"foo"}
```

Comment: Thanks for not just assuming jQuery! It sure looks much more attractive in this case though.

Comment: Failed to load: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and got through with following snippet:

> dojo.ready(function(){
>
> ```
>    var xhrArgs = {
>           url: "file:///Users/Desktop/configJSON.txt",
>           handleAs: "json",
>           load: function(data){
>
>            targetNode.innerHTML = data;
>
>                    // Your data from JSON
>                alert("Name : "+data.fields[0].name+" Type :          "+data.fields[0].type+" Alias : "+data.fields[0].alias
>                +" Editable : "+data.fields[0].editable);
>
>
>       },
>       error: function(error){
>                       // targetNode.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
>                       alert("An unexpected error occurred: " + error);
>               }
>               }
>
>               // Call the asynchronous xhrGet
>               var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
>           });
>
>       </script>
> ```

```
    </head>

    <body>

              <div id="licenseContainer"></div>
<body>
```